# Upload Data in MapQuest DMv2 through CSV using Data Manager API call

Tags: csv, mapquest

I need to upload data in MapQuest DMv2 through a CSV file. After going through the documentation I found following syntax of uploading data-

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/datamanager/v2/upload-data?key=[APPLICATION_KEY]&inFormat=json&json={"clientId": "[CLIENT_ID]","password": "[REGISTRY_PASSWORD]","tableName": "mqap.[CLIENT_ID]_[TABLENAME]","append":true,"rows":[[{"name":"[NAME]","value":"[VALUE]"},...],...]}
```

This is fair enough if I want to put individual rows in in rows[], but there is no mention of the procedure to follow to upload data through a CSV file. It has been clearly mentioned that "CSV, KML, and zipped Shapefile uploads are supported ". How can I achieve it though this Data Manager API service?

Answer (score 0):

Use a multipart post to upload the csv instead of the rows. You can see it working [here](http://developer.mapquest.com/content/tools/datamanager/).

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I used the CURL program to accomplish that. Here is an example of a CURL.exe command line.  You can call it from a batch file, or in my case, from a C# program.

```
curl.exe -F clientId=XXXXX -F password=XXXXX -F tableName=mqap.XXXXX_xxxxx -F append=false --referer http://www.mapquest.com -F "file=@C:\\file.csv" "http://www.mapquestapi.com/datamanager/v2/upload-data?key=KEY&ambiguities=ignore"
```